# I am having trouble with git push force

Tags: git

I created a project https://github.com/bksubhuti/Tipitaka-Pali-Projector.git
for my friend so we can keep  the changed files more easily and get the software in total .

My friend (the main programmer) is having trouble doing a git push and also and also git push origin master --force

or by doing the check box "force" for push in git-cola gui

He never did a checkout.. we don't have branches.  All he did was clone.
Is that the problem?

The problems.. 
First he created a user account in github.com
Then he created a user.name in git terminal.. but typed a wrong user name.

with that wrong local computer git username he did staging and commits
then the push failed because of wrong user name.
Then we figured that out but the push failed with error 1.
We tried the fetch several times, but that still did not resolve the problem.
So I told him to do

```
git push origin master --force
```

or to try using the "force" checkbox in git-cola (ubuntu)

He is really the only developer.  I just manage things so I don't care if he overwrites at this stage.  I also just want him to use GIT so I can get his changes instead of him passing me zip files.. some which have missing files from his changes.. and broken app.

We also have unreliable internet in Myanmar and maybe that failed too during upload.
I also deleted what looked to be duplicate files and junk.. but they might have been git specific files?  I think that git recovered from that mistake.

**How to get things going and fast to get things going.?**
Shall a reclone happen and burn a big download again 400mb?
Will this solve the problem ?
Is the repo messed up and a whole new one needs to be created?

Are his commits on the server and will a new clone still have the same mistakes?

I don't fully understand git myself.. I just know that in order to get the stuff loaded on the server you need to do 3 steps.  stage, commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

> First he created a user account in github.com Then he created a user.name in git terminal.. but typed a wrong user name.

If this is an authentication issue, no amount for git push --force would solve it.

The `user.name` setting is not that important, and has nothing to do with authentication.

It seems though that [Ariyavamsa](https://github.com/Ariyavamsa) (your colleague):

- [is a collaborator](https://github.com/bksubhuti/Tipitaka-Pali-Projector/commits?author=Ariyavamsa)
- has managed to push at least once ([commit 9fa1769](https://github.com/bksubhuti/Tipitaka-Pali-Projector/commit/9fa1769e12a4d53c6b1e7b296fcdc1691ca4adb0))

So make sure the issue is not related to a new commit too big for your network to handle.

The [OP Bhikkhu Subhuti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5980804/bhikkhu-subhuti) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133624/i-am-having-trouble-with-git-push-force/60134537?noredirect=1#comment106360024_60134537) an internet issue:

> We have bad internet.
>   He did an update on his system which was prolonged for a long time, and then could do a fetch and push with no problems.

Check first the `git status` output, after a `git fetch`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207492/discussion-between-bhikkhu-subhuti-and-vonc).